# Joining two meshes results in materials changing for one of the objects

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials

When I try to join (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>) two meshes, one of the objects changes its colour and loses its noise texture.

**Before (The vegetable on the right to be joined with plant leaves):**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

I have applied all the transforms to both the plant and the vegetable prior to joining so the scale etc. should be correct. The face orientation of both objects also seems correct before and after joining and also after recalculating normals.

Neither of the objects uses an image texture so I think UV Maps are not the issue, all the shading is done with nodes like *ColorRamp* and *Noise Texture* and unwrapping does not change how the objects look.

After joining I have tried playing around with the materials being assigned to the faces of the vegetable and they also appear to be the same materials as they were prior to joining.

Neither of the objects being joined has any active modifiers.

If it matters the material of the vegetable after joining also looks incorrect when it is rendered in Cycles.

Comment: It's hard to tell because we don't know what the shaders look like. Maybe it's because the object's size has changed and the procedural texture relies on it. Is there a *Mapping* node? Different values for the *Noise Texture*? What happens if you assign the material of the left bell pepper to the right one?

Comment: I'm failing to see the problem with your "After" (looks exactly like Before, so I'm missing something!).   Don't know why but ... I would try to first create a Vertex Group of all vertices in the pepper, then you can try to reapply the Material to that VG in the joined object.

Comment: @Blunder I think you're right, changing the noise texture for the vegetable material still changes what the material looks like but the scale is just now many times smaller. I'm guessing the most simple solution would just be to create a separate new material and go from there.